# Add effect for buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, effect

I have an app like Hangman, the difference is that in my app the letters chosen are in order, not on the right space .

```
-(void)MatchedWordClick:(id)sender{

    UIButton *bt = (UIButton*)sender;
    [bt setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    ((UIButton*)[PuzzleView viewWithTag:[[[lstWordToMatch objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]objectAtIndex:bt.tag-200] integerValue]+100]).hidden = FALSE;
    [[lstWordToMatch objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]replaceObjectAtIndex:bt.tag-200 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",-1]];
}


-(void)PuzzleWordClick:(id)sender{

    //AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound1);

    UIButton *bt = (UIButton*)sender;
    int nIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i< [[lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]length]; i++) {
        UIButton *bt1 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:200+i];
        if ([bt1.currentTitle isEqualToString:@""]||bt1.currentTitle == nil) {
            nIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (nIndex == -1) {
        NSLog(@"You Macthed Already");
    }else{

        bt.hidden = TRUE;
        [[lstWordToMatch objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]replaceObjectAtIndex:nIndex withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",bt.tag-100]];
       [((UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:200+nIndex])setTitle:bt.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }

    int nCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< [[lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]length]; i++) {
        UIButton *bt1 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:200+i];
        if ([bt1.currentTitle isEqualToString:@""]||bt1.currentTitle == nil) {
            nCount++;
        }
    }
    if (nCount == 0) {
        NSString *strWord = @"";
        for (int i = 0; i<[[lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]length]; i++) {
            UIButton *bt1 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:200+i];
            strWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",strWord,bt1.currentTitle];
        }
        if (![strWord isEqualToString:[lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]]) {
            MatchView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
            PuzzleView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
            ErrorAlertView.hidden = FALSE;

           // AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound3);


        }else{
            if (nCurrentWord == 0) {

                //// Change Points Value

                if ([[lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord] length] == 3) {
                    [lblPts setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nPoint+5]];//point value
                }else if ([[lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord] length] == 4) {
                    [lblPts setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nPoint+10]];
                }else if ([[lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord] length] >= 5) {
                    [lblPts setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nPoint+15]];

                }
                [self drawSuccessView];
            }else{

                nCurrentWord++;
                [self drawPuzzle:nCurrentWord];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working to select a letter and complete the word, it also works if I want to erase the letter and put it back .

I want that when I select a letter (from puzzle or from word) to add an effect like fly when a letter is put back or in the word.
I want something like this effect but I don't know how to do it in this case.

```
int z=40 + random() % 9;
    int w=40+ random() % 9;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.label13.frame = CGRectMake(-z,-200, 25, 25);
        NSLog(@"aaa");
    }];
```